Is it mandatory in German to use the singular in negative sentences like "none of the books here are on fire?"
I am working on a translation project into German and I have lines like the following:

Next to (or above) the bed you see a wooden closet filled with brightly colored books.
You can't make out any of the titles, though.
I am told it is quite horrible, without any trees or plants.
You don't need the bucket right now, because none of the books here are on fire.

These are all referring to having or seeing none of something. If I understand correctly it is common to use the singular in such cases in German where in English we would use the plural. For example I could translate the second sentence in the first line as "Du kannst jedoch keinen Titel ausmachen" instead of "Du kannst jedoch keine Titel ausmachen," and "without any trees or plants" could be "mit weder Baum noch Pflanze."
Is this necessary for all such cases? Is it wrong to use the plural, or just a matter of style?

I'd actually say the plural is ok in general, but it depends a bit on the circumstances - let's look at the individual examples:


You can't make out any of the titles, though.

To me, the following three translations sound natural:

Du kannst jedoch keine Titel ausmachen.
Du kannst jedoch keine der Titel ausmachen.
Du kannst jedoch keinen der Titel ausmachen.

In contrast, the following sounds a little bit off:

Du kannst jedoch keinen Titel ausmachen.

The only reason I can think of is that it slightly implies the narrator is expecting one combined title for all the books, rather than individual titles on the individual books. (Note that this is different for the above singular form with genitive, which xlearly talks about one out of many titles.)


without any trees or plants

It's fine1 to say "(ganz) ohne Bäume oder Pflanzen".
A singular way of saying this would be "ohne auch nur einen einzigen Baum oder eine einzige Pflanze", but it's unnecessary verbose for the semi-conversational tone your text appears to be written in, suitable maybe for actual prose text.


because none of the books here are on fire.

Here, all four forms sound natural to me:

da keine Bücher brennen
da kein Buch brennt
da keine der Bücher brennen
da keines der Bücher brennt

I would prefer the genitive forms as this emphasizes you are referring to the books at hand, rather than making a general statements about books. Then, I have a slight preference for the singular form, as the plural seems to suggest some of the books might be on fire in between others that are not. But as the same is arguably true in the singular form, the better phrase might anyway be

da die Bücher nicht brennen


1: If we disregard the slight weirdness of enumerating trees and plants, even though trees are plants.

"da keine der Bücher brennen" sounds weird to me.

@AnoE: Can you pinpoint why? To me, that sentence somehow conveys that it is expected some subset of the books might be on fire (but currently is not) - as opposed to "da keines der Bücher brennt", which sounds a little bit more "superficial" as the concern just appears to be whether anything is on fire at all.

I can't really pinpoint it - the other 3 sound perfectly natural. I do say that semantically, the first ("da keine Bücher brennen") seems to have a slight different feel than the 2nd and 4th, but 3rd really sticks out to me. For context, my own language is mostly Hochdeutsch with some decades of Bavarian exposure (though I don't talk that myself unless I make a conscious choice to do so). ;)

Agree, "da keine der Bücher brennen" does not work, it might be grammatically correct (maybe?) but if you said this to me Id think German is not your first language. I think its because you say eitther "ein Buch brennt" vs "kein Buch brennt" or "eines der Bücher brennt" vs "keines der Bücher brennt" or "Bücher brennen" vs "keine Bücher brennen", but there is nothing similar to "keine der Bücher brennen". Its just a guess, but maybe thats why it sounds weird?

@YanickSalzmann: The counterpart should be "einige der Bücher brennen".

Although "make out" literally translates to "ausmachen" in German, it still isn't what a native German speaker would say. Such literal translations always imply, that German and English native speakers prefer the same patterns to build sentences, and you just need to replace the English words with German words to get a proper translation. What you get by this method is a grammatically correct sentence if you'r lucky, but not necessary a sentence that a German native speaker would say. To translate an English text into German you need to know much more than just the vocabulary and basic grammar rules. Otherwise you get a bunch of clumsy sentences of which many even might be wrong.
Here are my suggestions:

Next to (or above) the bed you see a wooden closet filled with brightly colored books.

Verbatim translation (correct, but poor German, that is as close to the English original as possible)

Nahe (oder über) dem Bett siehst du einen hölzernen Schrank, gefüllt mit hell gefärbten Büchern.


What a German native speaker would say instead:

if the closet is standing on the floor next to the bed:

Neben dem Bett steht ein Holzregal mit grellbunten Büchern.


if it's hanging over the bed:

Über dem Bett hängt ein Holzregal mit grellbunten Büchern.



You use steht if it stands on the floor but hängt if it hangs on the wall. You don't use ist (is). Ist, when describing the location of something is correct, but poor German. We always tell the kind of positioning.
A Schrank is a closet with a door that usually stands on the floor. So it can't be above the bed. If it can be located above the bed, it is more likely a Regal (shelf) which hangs on the wall and has no doors. If it hangs and has transparent doors (i.e. glass doors), then it is a Vitrine. If it hangs and has opaque doors, it is a Wandschrank, but then you can't see what color the books are.



You can't make out any of the titles, though.

Verbatim translation:

Du kannst allerdings keine der Titel ausmachen.


What a German native speaker would say:

Allerdings kann man die Titel nicht erkennen.

Whenever you say you in English without meaning explicitly the person you are talking to, but just any person, then you don't use du or Sie in German. You use man instead.
You say ausmachen for make out only when the thing that can't be seen is too far away. It means, that you are not able to identify the place where it should be. If you can recognize the place, but still can't read the titles, maybe because it's too dark, then you don't use ausmachen. You use erkennen (recognize) instead.
»Man kann keine Titel erkennen« is fine. But this means that you are able to identify something, and this "something" is "no titles". Better is to say that you are not able to identify any titles, but even better is not to say "any titles" but "the titles".



I am told it is quite horrible, without any trees or plants.
This is not only just bad style, it is even wrong: »mit weder Baum noch Pflanze« You can't combine mit (with) with weder ... noch (neither ... nor)

Verbatim translation:

Mir wird gesagt, es sei ziemlich schrecklich, ohne irgendwelche Bäume oder Pflanzen.


What a German native speaker would say:

Man hat mir gesagt, dass es dort ohne Bäume und Pflanzen ziemlich trostlos ist.

We don't like sentences in passive voice. For situations like this we also prefer our beloved »man«. And we prefer dass-clauses over indirect speech.
Your sentence claims, that this is horrible always and everywhere. We don't like such absolute statements. Such a sentence doesn't come without any context, and in that context exists very likely a place about that you are talking. In German you refer to that place with dort (there).
And schrecklich (horrible) is a too plain and contour-less word. We prefer trostlos (bleak, dismal, dreary; literally: consolation-less) because it is more colorful and filled with more emotions than schrecklich. But that can be a question of personal flavor.



You don't need the bucket right now, because none of the books here are on fire.

Verbatim translation

Du brauchst den Eimer jetzt nicht, weil keines der Bücher hier brennt.


What a German native speaker would say:

Nachdem hier kein Buch brennt, brauchst du jetzt keinen Eimer.

The verbatim translation is acceptable. It's not so bad. I would prefer to put the cause (not burning books) before the consequence (not needing a bucket), but that might be my personal flavor. And I would say Kübel instead of Eimer because I live in Austria, and people in Austria and Bavaria prefer Kübel over Eimer.
»Keine Bücher« (plural) is also fine and good style, but I still think that singular sounds better in negations.





"Whenever you say you in English without meaning explicitly the person you are talking to, but just any person, then you don't use du or Sie in German." - this is true, but from the text samples and the other recent questions by the OP, I am getting the impression they are translating something like a text adventure (?) If that is the case, these descriptions of sensory input ("you see", "you can't make out") very concretely address "you, the player in front of the screen, reading this message".

@O.R.Mapper: You are right. That is exactly the problem when the posters of questions don't provide the question's context.

I disagree with the claim 'Although "make out" literally translates to "ausmachen" in German, it still isn't what a native German speaker would say.' I see this as a fully idiomatic use of meaning 4a from Duden or 5a from DWDS, namely to see/recognize something that is hard to see due to surrounding conditions (distance, (lack of) lighting, fog, ...). It is rather just used in written German in my impression, though.

@O.R.Mapper: DWDS defines this meaning of ausmachen as Seemannssprache, Jägersprache, Militär. I belong to non of these groups and I don't know any sailor, hunter or soldier. Maybe that's the reason why I never ever have heard someone use ausmachen in that meaning. I use: einen Termin ausmachen, das Licht ausmachen, den Motor ausmachen. Dass du mich anlügst, macht mir nichts aus.

"You can't combine mit (with) with weder ... noch (neither ... nor)"
Is there any situation where you can use two prepositions one after the other, other than als ob?

@odduse_of_language: Yes, there are many situations: »Aufgrund von Bauarbeiten ist das Geschäft bis auf weiteres geschlossen.« »Ich kenne ihn seit über 30 Jahren.« »Ich bin bis um ca. 14 Uhr beim Chef.« »Er stand inmitten von Brennnesseln.« »Die Entscheidung wurde innerhalb von wenigen Minuten zuungunsten von Dr. Schneider gefällt.« »Bis vor wenigen Tagen kannte er Maria noch nicht, aber jetzt ist er bis über beide Ohren in sie verliebt.«
